# В мобильной версии не работают ссылки как исправить?

Tags: php, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет.В моем сайте в мобильной версии не работает клик на ссылку. Точнее работает, только тогда, когда нажимаете два раза. В режиме ПК всё работает. Сайт называется muslim-shop.uz. Если какие то еще информации нужны могу отправить.

```
<li class="header-account dropdown default-dropdown">
                            <div class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <div class="header-btns-icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
                                </div>
                                <strong>My Account <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></strong>
                            </div>
                            <a href="user/signup" class="header-btns-icon-a">Логин / </a><a href="user/login" class="header-btns-icon-a">Вход</a>
                            <ul class="custom-menu">
                                <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])): ?>
                                    <li><a href="user/cabinet"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> <?=h($_SESSION['user']['name']);?></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> My Wishes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="user/logout"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> Выход</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Checkout</a></li>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <li><a href="user/login"><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> Вход</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="user/signup"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Регистрация</a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите со ссылок псевдокласс `:hover` для мобильной версии. `Hover` - на телефоне работает как промежуточное состояние и включается при первом клике, при повторном клике выполняется стандартное поведение элемента.

Comment: Сделал, не сработал